# Combine documents from folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with several letters separated with section breaks.

**What I want to do** is to break the document into several ones containing *X* number of letters (without manually selecting them).

**What I have done** is to separate it into individual letters with one macro (`BreakOnSection`), and then combine them with another one (`MergeMultiDocsIntoOne`) that open a file browser and allows me to select the files I want manually. Below are the macros.

**Main Question:** If the main document is divided into, let's say, 100 smaller documents, is it possible to modify the second macro, so it selects automatically 10 of them from a folder, merges/combines them creating a new document, and then goes on with another batch of 10, and so on?

> First macro:

```
Sub BreakOnSection()

'Criteria for moving through the document by section.
Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

'For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

    'Copy the whole section
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

    'Create a new document to paste text from the clipboard.
    Documents.Add
    Selection.Paste

    'Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\MyFolder"

    DocNum = DocNum + 1
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="letter_" & DocNum & ".docx"
    ActiveDocument.Close

    'Move the selection to the next section
    Application.Browser.Next

Next i

ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
'ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdSaveChanges

End Sub
```

> Second macro:

```
Sub MergeMultiDocsIntoOne()
  Dim dlgFile As FileDialog
  Dim nTotalFiles As Integer
  Dim nEachSelectedFile As Integer

  Set dlgFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With dlgFile
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    If .Show <> -1 Then
      Exit Sub
    Else
      nTotalFiles = .SelectedItems.Count
    End If
  End With

  For nEachSelectedFile = 1 To nTotalFiles
    Selection.InsertFile dlgFile.SelectedItems.Item(nEachSelectedFile)
    If nEachSelectedFile < nTotalFiles Then
      Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    Else
      If nEachSelectedFile = nTotalFiles Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
    End If
  Next nEachSelectedFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably, yes. What have you researched so far in this respect? Have you read articles on the use of `Dir` and `FileSystemObject` for working with files in directories?

Comment: Actually, those two macros are the only things I could find with respect to what I want to accomplish. I know how to use other programming languages, but I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Please search those terms (on Google, for instance) in combination with `VBA` and you should turn up tons of examples to get you going. If you have a specific problem with either of those approaches, edit it into your question (since it would not invalidate the answer already posted) and ask specifically about that problem. As it stands, this is rather "broad".

Answer (score -1):

Instead of breaking all the Sections into separate documents before recombining them, you'd do far better to simply split the original document into however multi-Section blocks you need. The following code will split any multi-Section document that you might want to break into equal Section counts:

```
Sub SplitDocument()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, StrTxt As String
Dim Rng As Range, Doc As Document, HdFt As HeaderFooter
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
j = InputBox("How many Section breaks are there per output document?", "Split By Sections", 1)
With ActiveDocument
   ' Process each Section
  For i = 1 To .Sections.Count - 1 Step j
    With .Sections(i)
       '*****
       ' Get the 1st paragraph
      Set Rng = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
      With Rng
        ' Contract the range to exclude the final paragraph break
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        StrTxt = .Text
        For k = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
          StrTxt = Replace(StrTxt, Mid(StrNoChr, k, 1), "_")
        Next
      End With
       ' Construct the destination file path & name
      StrTxt = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & StrTxt
       '*****
       ' Get the whole Section
      Set Rng = .Range
      With Rng
        If j > 1 Then .MoveEnd wdSection, j - 1
         'Contract the range to exclude the Section break
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
         ' Copy the range
        .Copy
      End With
    End With
     ' Create the output document
    Set Doc = Documents.Add(Template:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName, Visible:=False)
    With Doc
       ' Paste contents into the output document, preserving the formatting
      .Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
       ' Delete trailing paragraph breaks & page breaks at the end
      While .Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr Or .Characters.Last.Previous = Chr(12)
        .Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString
      Wend
       ' Replicate the headers & footers
      For Each HdFt In Rng.Sections(j).Headers
        .Sections(j).Headers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
      Next
      For Each HdFt In Rng.Sections(j).Footers
        .Sections(j).Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
      Next
       ' Save & close the output document
      .SaveAs FileName:=StrTxt & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
       ' and/or:
      .SaveAs FileName:=StrTxt & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
  Next
End With
Set Rng = Nothing: Set Doc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Word document and PDF output are both catered for.

As coded, it is assumed the output filename consists of the first paragraph in each group of Sections. If not, you could use a different range or replace all of the content between the ***** strings with code like:

```
' Construct the destination file path & name
StrTxt = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & (i + j - 1) / j
```

Comment: The document is auto-generated by another program, so I cannot change it.